# Why doesn't this simple WPF binding work?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a button which is bound to a filtered DataView (always 1 record):

```
<Button x:Name="btnValidate" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="3" Cursor="Hand" Click="btnValidate_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ValidationNoneBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding VALIDATED, Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border x:Name="bdrValidate" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Image Source="../Images/24/LocationSearch.png" Stretch="None" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

As you can see, I have a converter set for debugging, and it's working fine. The values I see passing through the converter are 0's and 1's. So why is the background not changing based on the Style Trigger? I can't figure it out ...

Comment: Does the image have transparent background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your converter is returning the integer 0 or integer 1? The `Tag` property is of type `Object`, so the XAML compiler assumes the "1" value in your trigger is a `string`, not an `int`

Either change your converter to return a `string`, or specify an `int` value in your trigger:

```
<Trigger xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Property="Tag">
    <Trigger.Value>
        <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
    </Trigger.Value>
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that since Tag is of object type that 1 value is considered a string and in case your property `VALIDATED` is an int.

As msdn states, [Trigger.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.value.aspx) does a [reference equality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183759.aspx) check.
And `Object.ReferenceEquals("1", 1)` is false.

If you modify your `VALIDATED` property to string it should work correctly.